# Python false value is considered a None?

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to update an xml value inside a JSON using beautifulsoup and xml.etree.ElementTree.
The field is called published with value false, so

```
<published>false</published>
```

For a reason I cannot understand, Python interprets the false value as None.
So I am trying to remove this field and recreate it, but ET.ElementTree is waiting an Element and not a None, so I cannot remove it.

Code:

```
metadata = root.find('{http://somehost.eu}metadata')
published = metadata.find('{http://somehost.eu}metadata')
if published is not None: //it never enters that
    published.text = 'true'
else:
    metadata.remove(published) // throws error of removing a None type
    published = ET.Element("published")
    published.text = 'true'
    metadata.append(published)
```

Any ideas what I can do?

Thank you

Comment: `published = metadata.find('{http://somehost.eu}metadata')` is not getting an element named `<published>`. That part of your code is wrong, and the result is probably `None`, not `'false'`.

Comment: Noo...you are right...it's fantastic how much time you may spend for somethnig obvious..Thanks a lot!